# How can I add conditions on my jq response in bash?

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, jq, aws-cli

I want write a script which is giving me the volumeId,instanceId and tags. But in tags just the "Name" is interest me.
I will elaborate.
today I am running with the next call

```
 aws ec2 describe-volumes  --filters Name=status,Values=available | jq -c '.Volumes[] | {State: .State, VolumeId: .VolumeId, Tags: .Tags}'
```

1. `"State":"available","VolumeId":"vol-094c79bc5e641bd7e","Tags":[{"Key":"Name","Value":"Adi"},{"Key":"Team","Value":"SRE"}]}`

2.`{"State":"available","VolumeId":"vol-041485dd7394bbdd7","Tags":[{"Key":"Team","Value":"SRE"}]}`

I want my response will include the just the tag `"Name"` and it's value.
If the tag "Name" does not exist , I want in my response just the `"State"`,`"VolumeId"`.

For 1.`State":"available","VolumeId":"vol-094c79bc5e641bd7e","Tags":[{"Key":"Name","Value":"Adi"}`
For 2. `{"State":"available","VolumeId":"vol-041485dd7394bbdd7"`}

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with `"Tags": []` holding an empty array while still being present, a simple `map(select(.Key == "Name"))` will do:

```sh
jq -c '.Volumes[] | {State, VolumeId, Tags: (.Tags | map(select(.Key == "Name")))}'
```

```json
{"State":"available","VolumeId":"vol-094c79bc5e641bd7e","Tags":[{"Key":"Name","Value":"Adi"}]}
{"State":"available","VolumeId":"vol-041485dd7394bbdd7","Tags":[]}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_pPnpzzbzI)

Otherwise you need to distinguish separately whether the field should be added or not. This can be achieved using an `if` statement:

```sh
jq -c '.Volumes[] | {State, VolumeId} + (
  {Tags: (.Tags | map(select(.Key == "Name")))} | if .Tags == [] then {} else . end
)'
```

```json
{"State":"available","VolumeId":"vol-094c79bc5e641bd7e","Tags":[{"Key":"Name","Value":"Adi"}]}
{"State":"available","VolumeId":"vol-041485dd7394bbdd7"}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/n9K2bneAkK)

Comment: Thanks, working perfectly.
1.Can you explain me or you familiar  with good explanation on map() function you used.
2. Can you explain what is the logic how I should know using Volumes. and when using .to get into a json or list ?

Comment: @AdiIsrael Try reading through the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/). It is organized into small parts and has examples to most of the functions (e.g. [map](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map%28x%29%2Cmap_values%28x%29)). Also, do actively play around with these examples, e.g. copy them into [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/) (which I have also used for the demos) and try modifying things.